# How to compute partial derivatives of a component of a vector-valued function?

Tags: pytorch, autograd

Let’s say I have a function Psi with a 4-dimensional vector output, that takes a 3-dimensional vector u as input. I would like to compute the gradient of the first three components of Psi w.r.t. the respective three components of u:

```
import torch

u = torch.tensor([1.,2.,3.], requires_grad=True)

psi = torch.zeros(4)
psi[0] = 2*u[0]
psi[1] = 2*u[1]
psi[2] = 2*u[2]
psi[3] = torch.dot(u,u)

grad_Psi_0 = torch.autograd.grad(psi[0], u[0])
grad_Psi_1 = torch.autograd.grad(psi[1], u[1])
grad_Psi_2 = torch.autograd.grad(psi[2], u[2])
```

And I get the error that u[0],u[1], and u[2] are not used in the graph:

```
---> 19 grad_Psi_0 = torch.autograd.grad(psi[0], u[0])
     20 grad_Psi_1 = torch.autograd.grad(psi[1], u[1])
     21 grad_Psi_2 = torch.autograd.grad(psi[2], u[2])

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py:275, in grad(outputs, inputs, grad_outputs, retain_graph, create_graph, only_inputs, allow_unused, is_grads_batched)
    273     return _vmap_internals._vmap(vjp, 0, 0, allow_none_pass_through=True)(grad_outputs)
    274 else:
--> 275     return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
    276         outputs, grad_outputs_, retain_graph, create_graph, inputs,
    277         allow_unused, accumulate_grad=False)

RuntimeError: One of the differentiated Tensors appears to not have been used in the graph. Set allow_unused=True if this is the desired behavior.
```

This is strange, as components of u are used to compute components of psi, so it should be possible to compute derivatives of the components of psi w.r.t to components of u. How to fix this?

**Answer**: based on answer from @Ivan, for higher-order derivatives, component-wise calls to gradient require `create_graph=True`, otherwise the same error happens as described above.

```
import torch

# u = grad(Phi) = [2*u0, 2*u1, 2*u2]
# Phi = u0**2 + u1**2 + u2**2 = dot(u,u)

u = torch.tensor([1.,2.,3.], requires_grad=True)

psi = torch.zeros(4)
psi[0] = 2*u[0]
psi[1] = 2*u[1]
psi[2] = 2*u[2]
psi[3] = torch.dot(u,u)

print("u = ",u)
print("psi = ",psi)

grad_v_x = torch.autograd.grad(psi[0], u, retain_graph=True)[0]
print(grad_v_x)
grad_v_y = torch.autograd.grad(psi[1], u, retain_graph=True)[0]
print(grad_v_y)
grad_v_z = torch.autograd.grad(psi[2], u, retain_graph=True)[0]
print(grad_v_z)
div_v = grad_v_x[0] + grad_v_y[1] + grad_v_z[2]

# Divergence of the vector phi[0:3]=2u0 + 2u1 + 2u2 w.r.t [u0,u1,u2] = 2+2+2=6
print (div_v)

# laplace(psi[3]) = \partial_u0^2 psi[3] + \partial_u1^2 psi[3] + \partial_u2^2 psi[3]
# = \partial_u0 2x + \partial_u1 2u1 + \partial_u2 2u2 = 2 + 2 + 2 = 6
d_phi_du = torch.autograd.grad(psi[3], u, create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]
print(d_phi_du)
dd_phi_d2u0 = torch.autograd.grad(d_phi_du[0], u, retain_graph=True)[0]
dd_phi_d2u1 = torch.autograd.grad(d_phi_du[1], u, retain_graph=True)[0]
dd_phi_d2u2 = torch.autograd.grad(d_phi_du[2], u, retain_graph=True)[0]

laplace_phi = torch.dot(dd_phi_d2u0 + dd_phi_d2u1 + dd_phi_d2u2, torch.ones(3))

print(laplace_phi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why is because `u[0]` is actually a copy so the one used on the following line:

```
psi[0] = 2*u[0]
```

is different to the one used here

```
grad_Psi_0 = torch.autograd.grad(psi[0], u[0])
```

which means they are not linked in the computation graph.

A possible solution is to assign `u[0]` to a separate variable such that it can be used on both calls:

```
>>> u0 = u[0]
>>> psi[0] = 2*u0
>>> torch.autograd.grad(psi[0], u0)
(tensor(2.),)
```

Alternatively, you can call [`autograd.grad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.grad.html) directly on `u`:

```
>>> psi[0] = 2*u[0]
>>> torch.autograd.grad(psi[0], u)
(tensor([2., 0., 0.]),)
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with a model showing the desired result.